# The parameters of anger in halacha

Tags: halacha, middos-character-traits

Although I cannot, at the moment, bring to mind specific examples of the Torah stating that it is absolutely forbidden to be angry or act out of anger, I seem to recall seeing this idea many times.

My question is: are there any situations where a Jew is allowed to be angry or act out of anger?

In addition, does it state anywhere explicitly and in a straightforward way that being angry is forbidden?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37531/is-getting-angry-a-biblical-prohibition

Comment: See here: http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2349458/jewish/How-to-Deal-with-Anger.htm

Answer (score 3):

Maimonides's *halacha* book, *Mishne Tora*, includes (*Deos* 2:3):

> Likewise, anger is a very bad trait, and it is fit for a person to distance himself from it to the opposite extreme. And he should teach himself not to anger, even about something that it is fit to be angry about. And if he wants to instill fear in his children and household members (or on the community if he is an officeholder) and wants to anger at them so they return to [do] good, [then] he should display himself before them as though he is angering so as to admonish them, but privately his mind should be settled: like someone who seems angry in his time of anger but isn't angry.

Comment: I think characterizing Hilchos deos as a "Halacha Book" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

every trait has its place as explained in Chovos Halevavos Gate 3 [ch.10](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=416#ch10)

> So, too, there are two traits - anger and satisfaction. Anger is in
>   place when you see a departure from the way of truth and the rule of
>   righteousness, when falsehood prevails over truth and those who follow
>   it.
>
> Pas Lechem commentary: when you see people turning away from the way
>   of truth, namely, the way of the torah of truth. He wrote "way of
>   truth" corresponding to the commandments between man and G-d and the
>   "rule of righteousness" corresponding to those between man and his
>   fellow. Behold, earlier regarding the trait of courage, he wrote "when
>   you meet the enemies of the L-ord". There the intent was on the wicked
>   who come to strike out at G-d's torah or His people, as written "For
>   behold, Your enemies stir, and those who hate You raise their heads;
>   Against Your people they plot cunningly, and they take counsel against
>   Your protected ones; They said, 'Come, let us destroy them from
>   [being] a nation, and the name of Israel will no longer be
>   remembered.'" (Ps.83:35). There showing anger to them is not enough.
>   Rather one must stand up against them and foil their plans, as written
>   there. For this one needs courage, which is strength of heart, to be
>   moser nefesh (self-sacrificing) in G-d's war, like David in the war
>   against the Philistines, especially in the battle against Goliath, or
>   like the Chashmonaim in the war against the Greeks. Here he is talking
>   about individuals who are being wicked by themselves, and it is enough
>   to show anger to them, to show them that you disapprove of their
>   deeds, and that their deeds are evil in the eyes of G-d. Through this
>   they will feel ashamed and perhaps they will repent.
>
> Marpe Lenefesh commentary: when people sway from the way of truth and when the
>   falsehood strengthens over the truth. Likewise it is permitted to be
>   angry at people of falsehood [who adopt the ways of falsehood].)